# Extending the self-adjoint operator $A:=\sqrt{-\Delta+1}$ to $H^{1/2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, self-adjoint-operators

I find myself studying the spectral theorem but fail to understand the following claim I just saw in an article.

Let $A:=\sqrt{-\Delta+1}$ be an operator. The operator $A$ on $L^2$ with domain $H^1$ (Sobolev space) is self-adjoint. Moreover its extension to $H^{1/2}$, which is denoted by $A:H^{1/2}\to H^{-1/2}$, generates a $\mathcal{C}^{0}$-group of isometries, $\left\{\mathrm{e}^{-itA}\right\}_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$, acting on $H^{1/2}$.

From what I see, since $L^2=H^{0}\subset H^{-1/2}$, then it makes sense to talk about an operator extension to a larger space.

**Question 1**: Why can the operator be extended to a larger space?

**Question 2**: Why does the extension turn out to be defined on the space $H^{-1/2}$?

What I know so far is that the Laplace operator is a self-adjoint operator in its maximal domain (Simon, Reed, Math Physics vol 2), but I can't understand why the operator $A$ can be extended.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think the extension of $A$ to $H^{1/2}$ is a density argument: You first prove that $\| Au\|_{H^{-1/2}}\lesssim \| u\|_{H^{1/2}}$ for $u\in H^1$ and use this to extend. The target space $H^{-1/2}$ is sort of dictated by the estimate above.

Comment: Couldn't you use a Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{I-\Delta}=I-\tfrac12 \Delta + \frac14 \Delta^2+...$ ?